# IIS 7.5 Enabling Test Certificate

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

For Testing x509 certificate.I expanded the Default Website node in IIS 7.5.When i right click there is no properties option in popup menu.How to include it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your server node (not website) and you should have a `Server Certificates` thing to go into.